# euler class of the normal bundle and self intersection number

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, intersection-theory

Let $S$ be a compact submanifold of $X$ smooth manifold. I know that $T_X|_S=T_S\oplus N_{S/X}$ where $N_{S/X}$ is the normal bundle. I have read that the euler class $e(N_{S/X})$ corresponds (via integration over S, i suppose) to the self intersection number $S\cdot S$. I've thought about it, but i don't know how to prove it, also i can't find the proof in any book. Do you know something about it?

Comment: To start: what is your definition of $e(N_{S/X})$?

Comment: IMO you are depriving yourself of some important suffering. 

Comment: Your statement that $T_X|_S = T_S \oplus N_{S/X}$ is not true.  There is an exact sequence relating these things, but it generally does not split.

Comment: @Jack: words like "compact", "manifold", and "integration" suggest to me that Konrad is working in the differentiable category, where he may split to his heart's content. 

Comment: @Konrad: How do you define the self-intersection "number" unless $\dim(X)=2\dim(S)$?

Comment: @Allen:  Fair enough.  I suppose I saw the tag algebraic-geometry and responded hastily.

Comment: This is typically a homework exercise, and I assume $S$ is a surface, where you have a complex line bundle $L\to S$ so that the Euler class is the 1st Chern class which is interpreted as the self-intersection number of the zero-section of $L$. The reason you would consider this splitting of $T_X|_S$ is to achieve the *adjunction formula* (in dimension 4).

Comment: My answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/696/euler-characteristic-of-a-manifold-and-self-intersection/700 can be adapted to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've just taught this in my graduate class.   Check these [notes on intersection theory.](http://www.nd.edu/~lnicolae/TopicsFall2011-Intersect.pdf)

The result you want is contained in Thm. 4.7.  Again, you need $2\dim S=\dim X$.

Comment: Your notes look very nice, thanks for sharing.

Comment: yes, i forgot the hypotesis $2dim S=dim X$, in particular $S$ is a complex curve in $X$. $S\cdot S=\int_X \eta_S\wedge \eta_S$. If $s_0:S\rightarrow N$ is the zero section of the normal bundle, to use thm 4.7 i guess you are impling that $\int_X \eta_S \wedge \eta_S =\int_N \eta_{s_0(S)}\wedge \eta_{s_0(S)}$.. but why is that?