# How to show the Euler Characteristic is equal to self-intersection number of zero-section

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes, euler-characteristics

myThe definition of the Euler characteristic (given in Guillemin and Pollack's "Differential Topology") of a compact oriented manifold $X$ is the self-intersection number of the diagonal $\Delta$ in $X\times X$, i.e. $\chi(X)=I(\Delta,\Delta)$.  I am reading notes on Characteristic classes, and in the first page the author reports that an equivalent definition is $\chi(X)=I(X_0,X_0)$, where $X_0$ is the zero section in the tangent bundle $TX$ ($X_0=\{(x,0)\in TX\}$).  How can I go about showing $I(\Delta,\Delta)=I(X_0,X_0)$?

The only differential topology I know is the first 3 chapters of Guillemin and Pollack, and my professor says this is enough to begin reading the notes.  When I tried to find this equivalent definition in the text, I found it stated as an exercise.  Thus, I believe it is true, but I'm struggling with proving it rigorously.  I know that $TX$ is diffeomorphic to the normal bundle of $\Delta$ via the map $(x,v)\mapsto ((x,x),(v,-v))$.  I also have that there is are neighborhoods $U$ and $V$ of $X_0$ in $TX$ and $\Delta$ in $X\times X$, resp., and a diffeomorphism $f:U\to V$ so $f(x,0)=(x,x)$ for all $x\in X$.  I feel like this should be close, but i'm missing the intuition to close the proof, or perhaps a trick or alternate way of seeing the question.  Thanks in advance to any solution/insight.

EDIT:  I do not believe this is a duplicate to the question mentioned in the comments.  That questions concerns the equivalence of the "self-intersection of the diagonal" defintiion and a cohomological definition.  The statement of my question can be found as an exercise in Guillemin and Pollack at a point before any algebraic topology is introduced, hence an answer to this question will be of a differential topology flavor.  Thanks for the link to the relevant question.  If you still feel this is a duplicate, can you please elaborate on how the questions are equivalent?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://mathoverflow.net/q/696/317.

Comment: I saw this before, but the linked question above asks why the "self-intersection of the diagonal" definition is equivalent to a "alternating sum of the dimensions of integral cohomology groups" defintion.

Comment: In any case, the "best answer" to that question may be useful, but it doesn't completely answer this question.

Comment: The self intersection of $\Delta$ in $X \times X$ is the same as the self intersection of $\Delta$ in a tubular neighbourhood of itself. But the tubular neighbourhood is diffeomorphic to $TX$ via a diffeomorphism carrying $\Delta$ to the zero section.

Comment: You may want to consult section 7.3 of these notes  http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Lectures.pdf  or   these notes http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/TopicsFall2011-Intersect.pdf